# Publish Ionic 2 app to play store

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

In IONIC 2, `ionic build android` generates 2 apk - `android-debug-unaligned.apk`, `android-debug.apk`, both are debug apk, how do I create a release apk to release in play store? Do we have publishing instructions like https://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html for Ionic 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ionic build android --release` worked and followed rest of the instructions from https://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the same flow after `cordova build --release android` which are mentioned in the URL you have provided. Keytool, jarsigner and zipalign performs the operations on the debug apk file you have generated by `ionic build android`. After these steps you should have and release apk file which you can publish in play store

Answer (score 0):

## Summary

Ionic Packages makes it easy to build a native binary of your app in the cloud. Perfect for developers using Windows that want to build iOS apps.

This lets you:

Send your packaged app to others
Build your app for platforms not supported by your computer (e.g. iOS builds on Windows)
Build .ipa and .apk files that you can submit to app stores

## Prerequisites

A Security Profile with App Credentials (see Android App Keystore and iOS App Certificate & Provisioning Profile)

## Building

The CLI must be used to package your app. The syntax is similar to ionic build. You must specify the platform. Additionally, you must build your app with a Security Profile (except for Android debug builds).

In the following examples, fill in the following:

PLATFORM_TAG    android or ios
PROFILE_TAG The Security Profile tag found in Settings › Certificates in the Dashboard

```
$ ionic package build PLATFORM_TAG --profile PROFILE_TAG
```

It first does an upload of your code and then queues your build in the cloud. Your build will be assigned an ID and will take a few minutes to complete.

### Release Builds

You can build your app for production by specifying the `--release` flag. You must have a production Security Profile with corresponding production Apple certificates.

```
$ ionic package build PLATFORM_TAG --profile PROFILE_TAG --release
```

## Build Information

Because your app is built asynchronously, you’ll need to check the status of your builds by listing them.

```
$ ionic package list
```

### Build Output

If a build fails, you can find out why by viewing the output.

BUILD_ID    The build’s ID found with ionic package list

```
$ ionic package info BUILD_ID
```

## Download

You can download successful builds. This will put the .ipa or .apk file in your app’s directory.

BUILD_ID    The build’s ID found with ionic package list

```
$ ionic package download BUILD_ID
```